# how to redirect / to related language folder with rewrite apache

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Basically I have a .htaccess file includes lines below ;

```
#1 / to /en|fr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule !^((?!(?:fr|en)).+?)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#2 add trailing slash /en to /en/ & /fr to /fr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([en|fr]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#3 /en/[index] & /fr/[index]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([en|fr]{2})/$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to redirect / directory to related language folder based on cookie

if cookie set to

```
lang=fr
```

it should end up with

```
/fr/
```

and if cookie set to

```
lang=en
```

it should end up with

```
/en/
```

So i do not want to stay at `/` directory anyhow. Once i am using rule#1 i got empty page even though page redirect to /en/ or /fr/. rule#2 and rule#3 works great. Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
#2 add trailing slash /en to /en/ & /fr to /fr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([en|fr]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Whilst this might just about work, this is not the correct pattern to match `/en` or `/fr`. You are matching any 2 chars from `e`, `n`, `|`, `f`, `r` (the characters within the *character class*). Instead, this should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

And a similar problem with rule #3:

```
#3 /en/[index] & /fr/[index]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([en|fr]{2})/$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

There is no `$2` backreference in this pattern. It looks like it should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that I have also added a slash prefix to the substitution.

Comment: nope it didn't work. i guess still there should be problem with rule#1. Otherwise rule#2 and rule#3 are working together as i mentioned on my question.